# Security issue with Azure

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-7, azure, full-trust

I need my application to run in FullTrust mode so I added this line to my web/config file:

I also modified the .csdef filr to enableNativeCodeExecution.

But when I want to run my application (which runs with no problems as a standard Asp.Net web app) I get the following message : "Role isntances did not start within the time allowed. Please try again. If you continue to encounter this behavior please try shutting down the Development Fabric."

And the following line on an event seen on the Event Viewer:
Exception message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file. (C:\dev\azure\Server\bin\Debug\Server.csx\roles\AzureServer\web.config line 91) [which is the line where the trust level is set]

Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

BTW: I'm running on a Windows7 box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we got this resolved on the Windows Azure forum, but you need to *just* set enableNativeCodeExecution="true" (and not set  in web.config).

Comment: that's right smarx, thanx... I'm having another issue but this one is solved as you mentioned